# Программа для ЕГЭ 2021 №27, Python

Tags: python, циклы, условия

Написал программу для решения 27 номера из примера ЕГЭ. Не могу понять, почему при изменении условия отбора внутри цикла выдает совсем другое число

[image: Задание 27 из примера ЕГЭ]

Первоначальный вариант:

```
File = open('27-B.txt', 'r')

file_read = File.read()
file_list = file_read.split()

file_list = [int(i) for i in file_list]
file_list.pop(0)

res = 0

for i in range(0, len(file_list), 2):
    i1 = file_list[i]
    i2 = file_list[i+1]
      
    if (i1 >= i2) and (((res + i1) % 3) == 0):
        res = res + i1
        
    elif ((res + i2) % 3) == 0:
        res = res + i2

print(res)

File.close()
```

Изменено elif на if:

```
File = open('27-B.txt', 'r')

file_read = File.read()
file_list = file_read.split()

file_list = [int(i) for i in file_list]
file_list.pop(0)

res = 0

for i in range(0, len(file_list), 2):
    i1 = file_list[i]
    i2 = file_list[i+1]
      
    if (i1 >= i2) and (((res + i1) % 3) == 0):
        res = res + i1
        
    if (i2 > i1) and (((res + i2) % 3) == 0):
        res = res + i2
            
print(res)

File.close()
```

Comment: в ```if - elif``` при true в ```if```, то, что в ```elif``` не будет проверяться, при ```if - if``` - и там, и там проверяется и, в случае true во втором if, изменит ваш res

Comment: да, но если первый if сработал, то второй не должен по тому что первое условие для него не должно выполняться

Comment: во втором варианте в elif нет условия (i2 > i1), т.е. в первом при невыполнении (((res + i1) % 3) == 0) дополнительно провериться только ((res + i2) % 3) == 0, а (i2 > i1) может быть и false... т.е. условия все таки разные

Comment: если i1 >= i2, то i2 > i1 не может быть верно, а если i1 >= i2 неверно, то i2 > i1 должно быть верно, по тому его и нет в elif

Comment: давайте попробую еще раз... 1-й вариант: ```(i1 >= i2) and (((res + i1) % 3) == 0)``` вернуло true&false, результат false (res + i1 не кратно 3), перешли к elif (при i1 >= i2), а в нем проверили только (res + i1) % 3... попробуйте вложить if-ы друг в друга (if (i1 >= i2): if (((res + i1) % 3) == 0): и т.д.), может, станет понятнее

Comment: кажется я понял, вариант с elif правильный, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что решение задачи выглядит вот так:

```
arr = [(1, 3), (5, 12), (6, 9), (5, 4), (3, 3), (1, 1)]

res = sum(max(obj[0], obj[1]) for obj in arr)

if res % 3 == 0:
    res = res - sorted(abs(obj[1] - obj[0]) for obj in arr if (obj[0] - obj[1]) % 3 != 0)[0]

print(res)
```

а можно сделать так в лоб:

```
res = 0
delta = 0

for obj in arr:
    res += obj[1] if obj[1] > obj[0] else obj[0]
    delta = abs(obj[1] - obj[0]) if (delta > abs(obj[1] - obj[0]) or delta == 0) and obj[0] != obj[1] else delta

res = res if res % 3 != 0 else res - delta

print(res)
```

Comment: Пока не могу понять правильно ли)

Comment: @incandescent, ну тут все просто - сначала мы получаем максимально возможную сумму как сумму максимальных элементов в парах, а затем если сумма делится на 3 мы вычитаем минимальную из разницы в парах которая не кратна 3, что дает нам сумму не кратную 3. Зачем нужна дельта? потому что это по сути замена одного числа пары на второе (из суммы вычесть первое число и прибавить второе, что равносильно просто вычесть дельту этих двух чисел) :))) Я привел второй код - он чуть подлиннее, но делает тоже самое и работает при этом чуть быстрее, поскольку все за 1 проход делается